# Variable replacement not working in ParallelTable

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, parallelization, scoping

The following code produces different results using `Table` and `ParallelTable`. `K` and `KK` are supposed to give the same result since `rule` is just also applied to `K` inside the table. However, the part using `K` with `ParallelTable` remains un`Replace`d for both `z` and `s`. This is like a minimal working example and I want to use `With`. What is wrong here? I'm using V13.1.

```
a = 0.2;
K = s Sqrt[(Sin[a]^2 - z^2)^2 - 4 (z^2 - Sin[a]^2)];
rule = z -> z0 + 4;
KK = K /. rule;

Table[With[{x = ({KK, K /. rule} /. s -> 1)}, x], {z0, 1, 3, 1}]

(*{{22.87325863762602`,22.87325863762602`},{33.90158745011456`,33.\
90158745011456`},{46.917922210598825`,46.917922210598825`}}*)

ParallelTable[With[{x = ({KK, K /. rule} /. s -> 1)}, x], {z0, 1, 3, 1}]

(*{{22.87325863762602`,s \
Sqrt[(0.039469502998557456` -z^2)^2-4 \
(-0.039469502998557456`+z^2)]},{33.90158745011456`,s \
Sqrt[(0.039469502998557456` -z^2)^2-4 \
(-0.039469502998557456`+z^2)]},{46.917922210598825`,s \
Sqrt[(0.039469502998557456` -z^2)^2-4 \
(-0.039469502998557456`+z^2)]}}*)
```

Comment: That same behavior goes all the way back to M8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `k` instead of `K`, which is system reserved.

[image]

[image]

In general, ([see here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/10397))

> Avoid single-capital-letter names for your variables

Or in general, always avoid variables starting in capital-letters, as they are likely to collide with system functions or variables.

This modified code works:

```
a = 0.2;
k = s Sqrt[(Sin[a]^2 - z^2)^2 - 4 (z^2 - Sin[a]^2)];
rule = z -> z0 + 4;
kk = k /. rule;

ParallelTable[
    With[
        {
            x = ({kk, k /. rule} /. s -> 1)
        }
        , x
    ]
    , {z0, 1, 3, 1}
]

(* {{22.8733, 22.8733}, {33.9016, 33.9016}, {46.9179, 46.9179}} *)
```

Also, please consider writing tidier code, [using scoping](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ScopingConstructs.html) and fewer variable assignments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!